# run feature files sequentially in cucumber

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have two questions.

1. I have 2 feature files . Loginpage (which is the first) and then Login(this is the 2nd). But when i run , always the second is picked up first because its alphabetically sorted. How do i make it in  sequential way.
2. I have two step definitions files. Now, the first runs ok but the second gives me a null pointer exception. How do i make the driver object catch that session from the first and continue executing for the second.

Thanks,
Sriharsha

Answer (score 0):

1. For this you can have the feature files listed in yml file, and then running each and every feature file in a sequential way by creating a gem. You can have a look at https://github.com/nareshnavinash/testbdd to get the idea of how this can be implemented.
2. I think you have to kill the driver at the end of first feature and initiate a new driver for your second feature file. If you badly want to use the same driver, then you have to merge two feature files.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks Naresh, I will check it.

Comment: But my question would be - can we write a single ton method for the browser ?

Comment: @DebanjanB thanks for your suggestion, will have that in my check list .

Comment: @sriharsha if you want you can try declaring the browser driver globally. But I havent tried that. But the best practice is to open the browser in the beginning of the feature and close all the browsers at the end of a feature file.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to test the Loginpage navigation and the login itself, you should separate them.


So the login test could include the navigation step and both can run independently.